# git push fails : returned error: 403 send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet -- not file size or permissions problem

Tags: git, gitlab

I am having weird problems pushing specific files to a gitlab server with the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

There are several other posts here on SO and elsewhere about that error - most seem related to either invalid credentials, exceeded file size limits or insufficient cache memory allocation. That does not seem to be the case here. I don't know what else could be the problem.

I have isolated the issue down to a problem with just 2 files that will not push successfully - one is a 44mb gif file so that's probably a size issue. The other file is a webm file at only 475kb.

I am perfectly able to push/pull everything else I have tried - so credentials are not the problem.

I am able to successfully push a 1.8mb webm file into the same directory as where the 475kb webm file fails - so file size is not the problem.

I have tried it several times on two different, very stable and fast networks - so connectivity is not the problem.

Below is a console print-out (with comments) of the following test.

- copied the 475 kb file **getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm** into the project
- staged it, committed it, pushed it
- FAILURE!
- reset HEAD, restored staging area, deleted the 475kb file and copied the 1.8mb file **getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm** into the project
- staged it, committed it, pushed it
- SUCCESS!

My local machine:
Linux LMDE (Debian 12).
Git version 2.39.2

The remote server:
GitLab Community Edition v16.7.2

```
# Git status
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git fetch
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

# Inspect file sizes
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ ls -l ../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/*.webm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soon soon  475346 Jan  7 16:06 ../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soon soon 1837630 Jan  7 16:06 ../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm

# Copy small file to project
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ cp -av ../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm ./getting_started/install/gfx/
'../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm' -> './getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm'

# Git status, add ., commit and push
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git add .
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git commit -m "Added a 475kB webm file"
[main c9deb99] Added a 475kB webm file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git push
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 407.70 KiB | 16.99 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 403 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 403
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

# Reset to Git previous commit, restore staging area and delete file
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git reset --soft HEAD~ 
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git restore --staged .
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ rm ./getting_started/install/gfx/navigation_link_at_bottom.webm 

# Copy large file to project
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ cp -av ../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm ./getting_started/install/gfx/
'../r4phd_backup/getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm' -> './getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm'

# Git status, add ., commit and push
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git add .
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git commit -m "Reset back to previous commit, removed the 475kb file and added another 1.8mb webm file"
[main 77a3318] Reset back to previous commit, removed the 475kb file and added another 1.8mb webm file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 getting_started/install/gfx/windows_check_installation.webm
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$ git push
Enumerating objects: 10, done.
Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Delta compression using up to 32 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.17 MiB | 1.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://gitlab.sdu.dk/soneill/r4phd.git
   95b32bb..77a3318  main -> main
soon@als1eg:~/Teaching/r4phd$
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by switching from https to ssh authentication.

Not really a very satisfying solution, but there we go...

Comment: The 403 status there is HTTP "Unauthorized" - your credentials were valid, but they didn't have permission to write. (`curl 22` is just cURL indicating that it's passing the error along.) Were you using a PAT that didn't have write permission?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, except I could indeed succeed in writing files to the remote repo using https - just not those specific files.